# Bulk Insert performance issues

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have 160k records I need to process and then store in a sql server table. I retrieve them from a staging table and do some validations and checks for missing fields or records that may already exist.

This is painfully slow in Entity Framework so I modified my code and looked to use `SqlBulkCopy`. I would look at Entity Framework extensions which I've used previously but my work doesn't want to take on the license fees for using it. Because I need to do validations and other checks on the data I need to pass a datatable to `SqlBulkCopy`, instead of doing the `IDataReader`.

This is where I'm having issues, its taken over 20 minutes to convert my `IEnumerable` entities to a datatable with 160k rows. Has anyone any ideas on how to improve this other suggestions which would be quick for doing a bulk insert with this amount of data?

Below is the code I'm using to populate the datareader. I originally had it all done in reflection but removed the adding of rows to be manual in hope it would be faster.

```
private static DataTable CreateRegisterDatatable(List<ApiRegisterData> apiRegisterData, List<Election> elections, IEnumerable<int> existingElectorIds, IEnumerable<int> missingElectionIds)
{
   var registerTable = new DataTable();

   foreach (var prop in typeof(Register).GetProperties())
   {
       DataColumn column = new DataColumn(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
       registerTable.Columns.Add(column);
   }

   foreach (var apiRegister in apiRegisterData)
   {
       if (!missingElectionIds.Contains(apiRegister.ElectionId) && !existingElectorIds.Contains(apiRegister.ElectorID))
       {
           DataRow row = registerTable.NewRow();
           row["ElectionID"] = elections[0].ElectionID;
           row["ElectorSuffix"] = apiRegister.ElectorSuffix.ToString();
           row["ElectorNumber"] = apiRegister.ElectorNumber;
           row["Title"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Title) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Title;
           row["FirstName"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.First_Name) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.First_Name;
           row["Initials"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Initials) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Initials;
           row["Surname"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Surname) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Surname;
           row["Suffix"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Suffix) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Suffix;
           row["IneligibleReason"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.IneligibleReason) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.IneligibleReason;
           row["Markers"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Markers) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Markers;
           row["Nationality"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Nationality) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Nationality;
           row["DOB"] = apiRegister.DOB is null ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.DOB;
           row["DateOfAttainment"] = apiRegister.Date_Of_Attainment is null ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Date_Of_Attainment;
           row["OtherElector"] = Convert.ToBoolean(apiRegister.OtherElector);
           row["StreetName"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.StreetName) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.StreetName;
           row["LocalityAddress1"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.LocalityAddress1) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.LocalityAddress1;
           row["LocalityAddress2"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.LocalityAddress2) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.LocalityAddress2;
           row["LocalityAddress3"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.LocalityAddress3) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.LocalityAddress3;
           row["PostCode"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.Postcode) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.Postcode;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress1"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava1) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava1;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress2"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava2) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava2;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress3"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava3) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava3;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress4"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava4) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava4;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress5"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava5) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava5;
           row["AbsentVoteAddress6"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ava6) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ava6;
           row["AbsentVotePostcode"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.avap) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.avap;
           row["ProxyName"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRegister.ProxyName) ? DBNull.Value : apiRegister.ProxyName;
           row["CreatedDateTime"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
           row["UpdatedDateTime"] = DateTime.UtcNow;

           registerTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    return registerTable;
}
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, but some improvement may be achieved by replacing `row["Something"] = value;` with logic that calculates `int somethingColumnIndex = registerTable.Columns["Something"].Ordinal;` outside the loop (I think I have that right) and then using `row[somethingColumnIndex] = value;` inside the loop.

Comment: it shouldn't take this long. But you have `IEnumerable<int> existingElectorIds, IEnumerable<int> missingElectionIds`, the Contains of those might be slow depending on the underlying datatype. Use Sets or whatever it's called in C# these days

Comment: Try plain ADO.NET, a dataset Fill from a SqlDataAdapter took two seconds to get 1M rows on my machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter

Comment: Tbh if performance is your primary criteria then ditch dragging the data out of the database, especially with an orm, use the database for what it's good at, processing data.

Comment: Also `!Enumerable.Contains(criteria)` will always loop thru all the enumeration so you may want to write that `if` statement backward `if (! (missingElectionIds.Contains(apiRegister.ElectionId) || existingElectorIds.Contains(apiRegister.ElectorID)))`

Comment: Thanks I'll try some of these suggestions. I was considering keeping the code in SQL but there are different scenarios etc and I wanted to be able to run my integration and unit tests to ensure nothing was missed. Didn't expect the performance to be so bad though!

Comment: I agree with @Stu - I see no logic on your code that can't be easily applied in T-SQL, so I truly don't see any benefit of using c# here.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproduceable example. Using your existing method (and making a few guesses), generating sample data locally for 160K records and inserting them using your method takes less than 2 seconds. ~ https://dotnetfiddle.net/vocvfv (you'll have to run this locally, it uses ~ 500MB memory, more than dotnet fiddle will allow)